# how to 'not' execute alias

Tags: bash, bashrc, alias

I have set few aliases in `.bashrc` file. I need those aliases most of the time, but sometimes I need to run those command without options set in that particular alias.

How to *not* execute alias command?

Answer (score 17):

Run the command with a leading `\`, an answer in examples: **;)**

```
% ls
bar  foo

% alias ls="ls -laog"

% ls
total 4292
drwxrwxr-x  4 4329472 Nov  5 15:06 .
drwx------ 95   28672 Nov  5 15:15 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1       0 Nov  5 15:06 bar
drwxrwxr-x  2    4096 Nov  5 15:06 foo
drwxrwxr-x  2    4096 Okt  2 14:29 .foo
-rw-rw-r--  1     191 Feb 25  2015 .htaccess

% \ls
bar  foo
```

---

Slightly longer but also possible:

```
command ls
```

Comment: Again, I have learned something new.  +1  =)

Comment: I really have not idea whose to accept

Comment: That's easy. Simply accept *your* favorite.

Answer (score 9):

You can use shell builtin `command` to escape aliases (and functions):

```
command alias_name
```

For example:

```
command ls
```

will run `/bin/ls` binary , not any alias defined as `ls`.

An alternative is to use quotes:

```
"alias_name"
```

or

```
'alias_name'
```

For example:

```
"ls"
```

or

```
'ls'
```

these again will run the `/bin/ls` binary, ignoring any alias `ls`.

Comment: Is this built-in `bash` specific  ? Also, upgoted for the double quotes

Comment: @Serg `command` is defined by POSIX..so it should be available to all POSIX compliant shells..

Comment: I really have not idea whose to accept

Comment: @edwardtorvalds my suggestion would be to accept A.B.'s one as it has come first and well directed..I think me & Serg won't mind at all :)

Comment: well that makes sense

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you could specify full path to command. For instance, my `ls` command is aliased to `ls='ls --color -F'`

What one can do is either call `/bin/ls`  or `$(which ls)` (for those of us who  are lazy to type full path).

Example : calling original command with flags `$(which ls) -l`

Comment: I really have not idea whose to accept

Comment: @edwardtorvalds A.B.'s is the simplest and most widely used, his is correct one , in my opinion